# Duplicate PRIMARY key error when writing UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update two tables using an UPDATE statement.  My goal is:
This script will delete the reservation for Lamar Lincoln from trip #562, 
and it will add a new reservation for Lamar Lincoln to trip #564. 
As an alternative, you may accomplish the same end with an update transaction.
However, I get an error stating the I have duplicate keys, 6-562?  Both trip_number and guest_id are PRIMARY keys, but Lamar (guest_id = 9) is on two trips, 562, 579.
[This is my DB design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3CLd.jpg)

```
use www;
UPDATE reservation
SET trip_number=564,
WHERE trip_number=562, guest_id=9;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the syntax suggested by Galz. If you get the same error, then there must be a record in `reservation` with `trip_number` 562 and `guest_id` 9.

**Best practice:** do not change primary key value after record creation, even for compound primary keys in linking tables like this one.

```
DELETE FROM reservation WHERE guest_id = 9 AND trip_number = 562;
INSERT INTO reservation (guest_id, trip_number) VALUES (9, 564);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing some syntax:

```
UPDATE reservation
SET trip_number=564
WHERE trip_number=562 AND guest_id=9;
```